# AccessibilityBundle files not found when I test my app with VoiceOver on

Tags: iphone, gesture, ios4, voiceover

When I try to test my app on my 4.3.2 device with VoiceOver turned on I get the following warnings:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.2 (8H7)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/UIKit.axbundle/UIKit (file not found).
```

Some google searching told me led me to delete my 4.3.2 folder in my DeviceSupport folder, but once Xcode organizer pulled the symbols from my iPhone again, the Accessibility stuff still wasn't there.

I also read that if I could use a previous version's accessibility files, but when I tried that I got a mismatched UDID warning.

The problem with all of this is that I am trying to get standard gestures in my app to pass through VoiceOver. I read this could be done if the user double-taps, holds, and then performs the gesture. But that isn't working right now, and I my best guess is that it's because of these warnings/ lack of Accessibility files.

I am in the process of updating my iOS version to 4.3.3 right now, so maybe that will fix it, but my connection is slow here and I'd like to know if there are any solutions to this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It had nothing to do with the warnings. Simply check "Accessibility Enabled" on the view in Interface Builder.