# Unable to read symbols for new iPhone, works fine for iPad, both running iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I get the following output for many missing files:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A334)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader (file not found).
warning: No copy of AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
```

As it mentions, it is slowing down my debugging session, as it takes a very long time for the app to load. It will load, but it is just unbearably slow.

Also, possibly related, I am unable to get a proper call trace on exceptions (though breakpoints are fine). 
Xcode mentions "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version" in the Organizer. I have a brand new iPhone 4s and iPad 2 running 5.0 (9A334). This issue only happens with the iPhone!

I have uninstalled all developer tools using the supplied shell script, then reinstalled from the App Store, and this issue still happens. I have also tried EVERY method I've previously found on this site, such as:

- Removing and adding the phone in the provisioning portal
- uninstalling and reinstalling xcode / dev tools
- removing specific sdk folders and
  having Xcode download them again

I even have an accepted answer dealing with this issue, but in my current case even my own answer will not suffice! [Issue with iphone sdk 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1)

EDIT: Also, I notice when attaching the phone that Xcode displays "Checking DDI symbols" for a moment.

Comment: "I have also tried EVERY method I've previously found on this site" doesn't provide us with much guidance—can you specify what you've actually tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could do to fix this issue was change the debugger to us LLDB. Nothing else worked, and I tried everything. Now that it's available, I'd rather use LLDB anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was setting up my 4S for development. However (and I imagine you've done this already), I had simply forgotten to click the "Use for Development" button in the Organizer (since I added the UDID to the Provisioning Portal manually).

Answer (score 1):

People have previously had this problem (missing files, not necessarily the same ones) and have solved it by manually copying the missing file from another version of the SDK, into the nominated SDK folder. Check out [the answer by ChrisL here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260291/issue-with-iphone-sdk-4-2-1). The alternative is a broader approach of [removing all iOS 5 SDK files and re-downloading them from the device as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215252/uuid-mismatch-detected-with-the-loaded-library). Note Andrew Vilcsak's post there suggests removing everything under device support but it should only be necessary to remove the iOS 5 folders; removing the earlier ones will not have any affect on your current problem (and could potentially create others?)

Given the particular files generating the error, another possibility identified in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496352/accessibilitybundle-files-not-found-when-i-test-my-app-with-voiceover-on) is that you need to simply check "Accessibility Enabled" in Interface Builder for one or more of your views. It seems like an odd solution given the error messages, but your situation does seem to fit with that of the other user there.

Re your possibly-related Xcode message, that's not a problem, as documented in [this Apple Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1569/_index.html):

> A: Why do I see "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this
>   version" in Xcode's Organizer window?
>
> The message "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this
>   version" is not an error; rather it's a notification that the version
>   of the iPhone OS installed on the plugged in device does not have a
>   corresponding restore image for Xcode to use.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation of the Organizer message. However, I've definitely tried a few flavors of removing/readding those folders. That's what baffles me.

Comment: Have added to the answer the possibility regarding the "Accessibility Enabled" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to check all your `IBOutlet` references in iphone xibs.
2. This error may be resolved by **Clean**->**Build** as well.

Comment: can you elaborate on checking the outlets? I don't receive any warnings/errors about not being able to link up to an outlet, or any key value errors

Comment: i meant some IBOutlet has several invalid name or actions. But now i see that all OK with your outlets.